# IntelliJ IDEA on Lion Menu no response

Tags: osx-lion

My OS is Mac OS X 10.7 Lion, and I'm using the IntelliJ 10.5.2, the latest version by now.

After IntelliJ opened, the menu on the top of screen does not give me any response when clicking it. Is anyone meet the similar problem like this? Is the problem caused by JRE or Lion?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place for this.  The [IntelliJ Devnet Community](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/ideacommunity?view=discussions) would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you disable the screen menu bar for IntelliJ IDEA by editing Info.plist file in its .app Contents directory?

```
    <key>apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar</key>
    <string>false</string>
```

If the application still hangs, please contact JetBrains support with a [thread dump](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-260).

Answer (score 0):

What JDK are you using ? I have no issue with a similar environment, please try to wipe your IDEA settings (in ~/Library)